# Convert Rails Active Record scope to Java Spring Boot with QueryDsl

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, querydsl

In Ruby on Rails you can define scopes in an Active Record model like

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord

      scope :viewed, -> { order("articles.views DESC") }
      scope :ordered, -> { order("articles.title ASC") }
      scope :latest, -> { order("articles.created_at DESC") }
```

And then chain queries and reuse them like

```
Article.select('articles.*, COUNT(comments.id) AS total').joins(:comments).viewed.ordered.latest
```

I'd like to know how to accomplish the reusable pattern with Java Spring Boot using QueryDsl if it is possible.